# select2 rails search by filter options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-select2, select2-rails

maybe someone of you guys is able to help me with this.

Lets say I have a book Model.
I want to search for all of my book titles, which I have already done now with the help of select2rails. Each book belongs to a category, and I want to enable a 'filter' function where I select a category and my search bar shows me all results but only within the category that was selected.

for example :

I have a book named lord of the rings which belongs to the category fantasy. I also have a book lord of the family which belongs to the category family. when i enter lord in the search bar both titles will be shown, but I want to have the option to select a category.

(I've read the documentation about select2 and wasn't able to find anything that would help me with this.)

example : category selected = fantasy

I type in lord and only lord of the rings will be shown.

How do I achieve this?

```
<!-- Search Widget -->
<div class="card my-auto">
  <%= form_with url: books_path , method: :get, local: true  do |f| %>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>Search for a Book title.</p>
      <%= f.collection_select(:book_id, Book.all, :id, :title, {include_blank: 'Book titles'}, {class:'selectbooktitle form-control'}) %>
      <hr>
      <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <%= f.submit 'Search', class: 'btn btn-outline-success', method: :put %>
                </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

book.rb

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy

  has_attached_file :book_cover, styles: { book_index: '250x350>', book_show: '325x475>' }
  validates_attachment_content_type :book_cover, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```

books_controller

```
def index

    if params[:category].blank?
      @books = Book.all.order('created_at DESC')
    else
      @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
      @books = Book.where(category_id: @category_id).order('created_at DESC')
    end
    return redirect_to book_path(params[:book_id]) if params[:book_id]
  end
```

Comment: The question is not very clear. Are you asking about what is shown in the search bar? Or about the results after click in the search button? The controller seems that is returning the results filtered by category.

Comment: I just want a feature to select a category from my category model.
https://luna1.co/1cd6c1.png - could be something like this.
Maybe a dropdown that you can click and select a category from, which makes the search a little more detailed.